# Dynamic where clause with loop linq c#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have dictionary with regular expressions and a data table.

```
var data = ds.Tables["mytable"].AsEnumerable();

var regexlist = new Dictionary<string, Regex>
{
     {"PI1", new Regex(@"(-.[^I](-P[^IS]))|(-[^P].(-P[^IS]))")},
     {"SM1", new Regex("(-.[^I](-P[^IS]))|(-[^P].(-P[^IS]))")}
};
```

Now I want to select all rows of the data table that does not match the regular expressions in the list and also the key of the dictionary (the error code).

So far I have this:

```
var query = data.Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("F1"));
query = regexlist.Aggregate(query, (current, regex1) => current.Where(u => regex1.Value.IsMatch(u) ));
```

but I think that only the first regex is added as where clause.
And I don't know how to output the "error code"

I hope I explained my problem clear.

jonas

Answer (score 0):

Whole things looks OK except that Where expression that doesn't reflect your objective, you need to invert test clause to get data that does not match regex'es

```
current.Where(u => regex1.Value.IsMatch(u) == false)
```